# Best pattern to be used for multiple payment gateways

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, architecture

**Requirement:**

I have requirement to integration with multiple payment gateways. However the client uses only one of the available, and that is configured using admin settings.

**Current System:**

I have written one library each per payment gateway. Which creates a maintenance nightmare and potential increase in projects as the gateway integration requests (sources) increase.

**Question**

Can someone suggest me a design pattern to use in this scenario, to may be create interfaces and common settings and implement the gateway as required which reduces duplicate code?

Comment: You have answered your own question in my opinion

Comment: I'd go and look and see how the likes of NopCommerce do it. If I recall correctly, they have one plugin per provider and almost certainly there is at least one interface in play too.

Comment: how about strategy design pattern?

Comment: If you have some code that is repeating across your various payment project libraries,   then create another project in which you define an abstract payment class that all your other payment providers derive from.  So,  now all common code across multiple projects is in one abstract class and its easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a standard interface to deal with the common operations. Have a set of domain objects that are passed into those methods.

For example, to create a payment you might have a PaymentCardDetails model, an AddressModel etc. Your interface would have a method MakePayment or similar, e.g.:

```
public MakePaymentResponse MakePayment(PaymentCardDetails cardDetails, AddressModel address);
```

Then each of your payment gateways should implement this interface using their own implementation.

Then use IoC (Inversion of Control) / DI (Dependency Injection) to decide which interface to use at runtime based on a provided config value.

In the methods in your code that use the payment gateways you would pass in the interface using constructor injection, your DI framework would take care of picking the right implementation. e.g.

```
public class Payment {

    private readonly IPaymentGateway _paymentGateway;

    public Payment(IPaymentGateway paymentGateway) {
        _paymentGateway = paymentGateway;
    }

    public MyMethod() {
        //get your models prepared etc.
        _paymentGateway.MakePayment(cardDetails, addressDetails);
    }
```